# Outputting RPi video into a laptop

Tags: webcam, output, laptop

I've been researching on how to get my RPi video output to show up on my laptop. Space requirements dictates that using an external monitor is extremely cumbersome, and since I'm not using my home network, setting up an ssh and remote desktop, while doable, is unstable and a pain to deal with.

Everything that I'm reading says that you cant input an HDMI signal into an HDMI out, but it doesn't take a genius to figure that out. I'm wondering if there's a device that can take the HDMI signal from the Pi and have my computer interpret it as something like a webcam input.

I have found that people are using capture cards to take HDMI from a camera and use it for a facecam while on live streams, but every resource that I'm reading is suggesting $150 hardware that is "4k 60 fps capable" which is extreme overkill. Anybody who asks about cheaper hardware is told that it is bad and won't last long.

I don't need anything with a high res or low latency, I just need something that works.

Comment: I've never seen a consumer laptop (under £700) with video in. Does your system have that? If not look at screen sharing with RealVNC.

Comment: No, no video in. That's why I'm asking about this piece of hardware. With my Pi at least, I'm finding using software such as VNC a bit of a pain because the connection will drop if I don't send a command every 10 seconds or so. Also, every time that I reflash the boot SD, I have to go through and find the IP addresses again. I'd rather have more of a hardware solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you well said, you can't output HDMI video into a laptop. 
I don't know of any devices as of now, however, I recommend using VNCServer and Viewer. 
It's almost as simple as using an HDMI. Just install VNC Server in your raspberry using [these steps](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/). Install VNC Viewer in your laptop and connect the raspberry with the laptop with an UTP cable (The one you use to connect to ethernet). That will help the instability, it doesn't have anything to do with a home-network. It will be its own network, just between the raspberry and your laptop ethernet interface.

Comment: All attempts to SSH and remote desktop, through UTP or Wi-fi, had moments where the feed would drop after idling for more than a few seconds. It was a real pain to deal with.

Comment: I don't know which method you're using. I use a remote desktop while working with my raspberry all the time and it works wonders. Maybe check your raspberry configuration?